# Optimizing Colisons to stop infinite colisions

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a simple project of simulating how gravity affects diferent objects in canvas but i'm having a problem with my code.

The problem is that my objects are causing infinite colisions when there are to many objects on the bottom of the canvas.

```
const W = canvas.width,
  H = canvas.height;

class BasketBall {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.R = 10;
    this.COLOR = "orange";
    this.outlineColor = "black";
    this.outlineWidth = 1;
    this.lastCollisionTime = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.A = 0.2;
    this.dX = 0; // Velocidade no eixo X
    this.dY = 0;
  }

  draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.COLOR;
    ctx.strokeStyle = this.outlineColor; // Set the outline color
    ctx.lineWidth = this.outlineWidth; // Set the outline width
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.R, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke(); // Stroke the circle to create an outline
  }

  update() {
    this.x += this.dX;
    this.y += this.dY;

    if (this.x - this.R < 0) {
      this.x = this.R;
      this.dX = -this.dX;
    }
    if (this.x + this.R > W) {
      this.x = W - this.R;
      this.dX = -this.dX;
    }

    if (this.y > H - this.R) {
      this.y = H - this.R;
      this.dY = -this.dY * 0.6; // Inverta a velocidade vertical e reduza a força do salto
    } else {
      this.dY += this.A;
      this.y += this.dY;
    }
  }

  getButtonColor() {
    return this.COLOR;
  }
}

class Cannon {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.R = 20;
    this.COLOR = "black";
    this.outlineColor = "black";
    this.outlineWidth = 1;
    this.lastCollisionTime = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.A = 0.5;
    this.dX = 0;
    this.dY = 0;
  }

  draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.COLOR;
    ctx.strokeStyle = this.outlineColor; // Set the outline color
    ctx.lineWidth = this.outlineWidth; // Set the outline width
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.R, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke(); // Stroke the circle to create an outline
  }

  update() {
    this.x += this.dX; // Atualize a posição no eixo X
    this.y += this.dY;

    // Adicione lógica para lidar com colisões nas bordas do canvas
    if (this.x - this.R < 0) {
      this.x = this.R;
      this.dX = -this.dX * 0.1; // Inverta e reduza a velocidade no eixo X
    }
    if (this.x + this.R > W) {
      this.x = W - this.R;
      this.dX = -this.dX * 0.1; // Inverta e reduza a velocidade no eixo X
    }

    if (this.y > H - this.R) {
      this.y = H - this.R;
      this.dY = -this.dY * 0.1; // Inverta e reduza a velocidade no eixo Y
    } else {
      this.dY += this.A;
      this.y += this.dY;
    }
  }

  getButtonColor() {
    return this.COLOR;
  }
}

class PingPong {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.R = 5;
    this.COLOR = "white";
    this.outlineColor = "black";
    this.outlineWidth = 1;
    this.lastCollisionTime = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.A = 0.3;
    this.dX = 0; // Velocidade no eixo X
    this.dY = 0;
  }

  draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.COLOR;
    ctx.strokeStyle = this.outlineColor; // Set the outline color
    ctx.lineWidth = this.outlineWidth; // Set the outline width
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.R, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke(); // Stroke the circle to create an outline
  }

  update() {
    this.x += this.dX;
    this.y += this.dY;

    if (this.x - this.R < 0) {
      this.x = this.R;
      this.dX = -this.dX;
    }
    if (this.x + this.R > W) {
      this.x = W - this.R;
      this.dX = -this.dX;
    }

    if (this.y > H - this.R) {
      this.y = H - this.R;
      this.dY = -this.dY * 0.8; // Inverta a velocidade vertical e reduza a força do salto
    } else {
      this.dY += this.A;
      this.y += this.dY;
    }
  }

  getButtonColor() {
    return this.COLOR;
  }
}

const objects = [];

canvas.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  const mouseX = event.clientX - rect.left;
  const mouseY = event.clientY - rect.top;

  let newObject;

  switch (currentObjectClass) {
    case "BasketBall":
      newObject = new BasketBall(mouseX, mouseY);
      break;
    case "Cannon":
      newObject = new Cannon(mouseX, mouseY);
      break;
    case "PingPong":
      newObject = new PingPong(mouseX, mouseY);
      break;
  }

  if (newObject) {
    objects.push(newObject);
  }
});

// Função de detecção de colisões
function checkCollision(obj1, obj2) {
  const dx = obj1.x - obj2.x;
  const dy = obj1.y - obj2.y;
  const distanceSquared = dx * dx + dy * dy;
  const sumOfRadiiSquared = (obj1.R + obj2.R) ** 2;

  return distanceSquared < sumOfRadiiSquared;
}

// Lógica de colisões
function handleCollisions() {
  for (let i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < objects.length; j++) {
      const obj1 = objects[i];
      const obj2 = objects[j];

      if (checkCollision(obj1, obj2)) {
        const dx = obj2.x - obj1.x;
        const dy = obj2.y - obj1.y;
        const distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

        if (distance < obj1.R + obj2.R) {
          const angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
          const overlap = (obj1.R + obj2.R - distance) * 0.5;

          const targetX1 = obj1.x - Math.cos(angle) * overlap;
          const targetY1 = obj1.y - Math.sin(angle) * overlap;
          const targetX2 = obj2.x + Math.cos(angle) * overlap;
          const targetY2 = obj2.y + Math.sin(angle) * overlap;

          obj1.x = targetX1;
          obj1.y = targetY1;
          obj2.x = targetX2;
          obj2.y = targetY2;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to change the handleCollisions() and the objects.

i wanted the objects to eventualy stop and stack on top of eachother verticaly.

Comment: You're modifying the objects' coordinates while you're iterating over them, which will lead to some additional instability. You'll need to compute all new values first, then assign them to the objects after the outer loop.